# ES Spring data add size into spring data format

Tags: spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to convert my JSON ES query to Java I am using Spring data. I am almost there but  the problem is i cannot get the `"size": 0` into my query in Java.

```
GET someserver/_search
{
   "query": { ...},
   "size": 0, 
    "aggregations" : {
    "parent_aggregation" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field": "fs.id"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "sub_aggs" : {
            "top_hits": {
              "sort": [
                  {
                    "fs.smallVersion": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 1
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In Java I am building an NativeSearchQuery object on which I think it should be possible to set the size?

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = createNativeSearchQuery(data, validIndices, query, filter);
es.getElasticsearchTemplate().query(searchQuery, response -> extractResult(data, response));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using elasticsearch before 2.0, you can use the search type feature to do what you want, which is not return docs. This can be accomplished using the NativeSearchQueryBuilder. If you set the SearchType to COUNT you will not get docs. Beware that in elasticsearch 2.x this is deprecated and you should use the size is 0. If the spring elasticsearch project will support elasticsearch 2.0 this will most likely change and the size attribute should be exposed in this builder as well.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .withSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)
            .withIndices("yourindex")
            .addAggregation(terms("nameofagg").field("thefield"))
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jettro, but how can i set the "size": 0 in java? I am using Es 1.3.4, Setting SearchType.COUNT give me 0 resulsts while in JSON "size":0 is giving me 4 results

Comment: I am afraid the only way to do it with spring data is to use the Pageable: Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));

Comment: Maybe use the count query? But I guess that does not allow you to do aggregations.

Comment: When i add the SearchType.Count I get zero results. I think the point of adding the size:0 to the query is giving me distinct documents based on fs.id and fs.smallversion.

In JSON for example when if have a 
fs.id 998.1
and 998.2

Only document 998.2 is returned which is what i need. But i am not able to do it with the spring data Elastich search api

Comment: Adding size:0 zero to a query tells elasticsearch to only count the documents and not to return any documents. Since it does not need to return documents the score also is not calculated. Which is a performance optimisation if you only want aggregate results and no documents.

Comment: The problem with aggregation is that it does not support pagination. The way we are solving this now is by adding an extra field to the document which keep track of the latest version.